# Why does rtpbin example from Gstreamer not work?

Tags: gstreamer

I am trying to run the [rtpbin example](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/rtpmanager/rtpbin.html?gi-language=c) an Ubuntu 21.10 VirtualBox VM with GStream 1.18.5.

- I set up GStreamer and have been able to run many of the [basic](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/index.html?gi-language=c) and [playback](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/playback/index.html?gi-language=c) tutorials.
- I've also read through a good portion of [Application Developer Manual](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/index.html?gi-language=c).

Doing everything from C code seems straightforward but the `rtpbin` example uses `gst-launch-1.0` (covered in [one of the basic tutorials](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/gstreamer-tools.html?gi-language=c)).

I couldn't get the `rtpbin` example to run without errors initially:

- `ffenc_h263` and `ffdec_h263` (`WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "ffenc_h263"`), so I replaced them with `avenc_h263` and `avdec_h263`, respectively
- `v4l2src`was looking for a device that wasn't available in `/dev` so I switched to `videotestsrc`.

To make sure these substitutions weren't a problem, I got rid of the RTSP and UDP stuff and checked by running:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! avenc_h263 ! rtph263pay \ 
    ! rtph263depay ! avdec_h263 ! xvimagesink
```

and saw the "bars" video. I also ran

```
gst-launch-1.0 audiotestsrc ! amrnbenc ! rtpamrpay ! rtpamrdepay ! amrnbdec ! alsasink
```

and heard that annoying test tone. Based on this, I think the issue is with UDP and  RTSP.

Running

```
 gst-launch-1.0 rtpbin name=rtpbin \
         videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! avenc_h263 ! rtph263pay ! rtpbin.send_rtp_sink_0 \
                   rtpbin.send_rtp_src_0 ! udpsink port=5000                            \
                   rtpbin.send_rtcp_src_0 ! udpsink port=5001 sync=false async=false    \
                   udpsrc port=5005 ! rtpbin.recv_rtcp_sink_0                           \
         audiotestsrc ! amrnbenc ! rtpamrpay ! rtpbin.send_rtp_sink_1                   \
                   rtpbin.send_rtp_src_1 ! udpsink port=5002                            \
                   rtpbin.send_rtcp_src_1 ! udpsink port=5003 sync=false async=false    \
                   udpsrc port=5007 ! rtpbin.recv_rtcp_sink_1
```

shows

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
0:00:59.0 / 99:99:99 # This is counting up
```

Then in a different window, I run

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtpbin name=rtpbin                                          \
     udpsrc caps="application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=(string)H263-1996" \
             port=5000 ! rtpbin.recv_rtp_sink_0                                \
         rtpbin. ! rtph263depay ! avdec_h263 ! xvimagesink                    \
      udpsrc port=5001 ! rtpbin.recv_rtcp_sink_0                               \
      rtpbin.send_rtcp_src_0 ! udpsink port=5005 sync=false async=false        \
     udpsrc caps="application/x-rtp,media=(string)audio,clock-rate=(int)8000,encoding-name=(string)AMR,encoding-params=(string)1,octet-align=(string)1" \
             port=5002 ! rtpbin.recv_rtp_sink_1                                \
         rtpbin. ! rtpamrdepay ! amrnbdec ! alsasink                           \
      udpsrc port=5003 ! rtpbin.recv_rtcp_sink_1                               \
      rtpbin.send_rtcp_src_1 ! udpsink port=5007 sync=false async=false
```

and see

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
```

I expect to see some UDP ports open (5000, 5001, 5002, 5003, 5005, and 5007). Sure enough, running `netstat` shows:

```
rtsp@rtsp-VirtualBox:~$ sudo netstat -apn | grep -w 500[0-9]
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5000            0.0.0.0:*                           7076/gst-launch-1.0 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5001            0.0.0.0:*                           7076/gst-launch-1.0 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5002            0.0.0.0:*                           7076/gst-launch-1.0 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5003            0.0.0.0:*                           7076/gst-launch-1.0 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5005            0.0.0.0:*                           6862/gst-launch-1.0 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5007            0.0.0.0:*                           6862/gst-launch-1.0
```

To make sure all the ports were working

- I installed from snap `rtsp-test-server` and VLC
- I was able to stream video over the ports provided by `rtsp-test-server`.
  I suppose this isn't a perfect test since TCP ports are being used instead of UDP but it was easy to test so I gave it a shot.

But I'm not seeing any video or hearing any sound. Can someone point out my error(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was almost ready to submit my question and I did one more Internet search. I found [this tutorial](https://michael.franzl.name/blog/posts/2018-03-05-gstreamer-pipeline-recipe-stream-file-via-rtp-using-rtpbin) which shows several extra flags added to the `udpsrc` and `udpsink` elements. Adding the following flags got the example working so that I could see video and hear sound via RTSP:

- `host=127.0.0.1` on all `udpsink` elements
- `address=127.0.0.1` on all `udpsource` elements

I think the other flags in that tutorial that I left off are likely the defaults.

Comment: could you please not only link to the solution, because it appears to be broken. is the only thing you changed the host= and address= parameters?

Comment: @activedecay For now, I've updated the link.